# How to map composite key of entity in JPA?

Tags: jpa

I have the REGION table:

```
REG {
    id number,
    dateCreation Date
  }
```

I have a LOCALE table:

```
LOCALE {
     locale String
  }
```

I have a REGION_DESCRIPTION table:

```
REGION_DESCRIPTION {
     locale String,
     regId number,
     description
  }
```

REGION_DESCRIPTION has a composite key: locale is a foreign key pointing to the LOCALE table. And regId points to the REGION table.

I would like to map this to my Region java class:

```
private List<RegionDescription> descriptions;
```

I tried different approache in JPA. But I cannot get the mapping to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have a case of a join table (REGION_DESCRIPTION) becoming an entity by carrying its own attributes. I would suggest the following:

1. define *RegionDescription* as a
   complete entity with composite
   primary key class, see [example](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg001.htm#BCGGGDDC);
2. define 2 many-to-one relationships in *RegionDescription*:
   *RegionDescription* to *Region* and
   *RegionDescription* to *Locale*.
3. alternatively or in addition define
   one-to-many relationship in *Region*
   to map *RegionDescription*'s the way
   you specified above.

Comment: @Jyotirup - here we go http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/cmp30cfg001.htm

Answer (score 2):

This should fill your needs:

```
@Entity
public class Region
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreation;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "region")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "region_id")
    private List<RegionDescription> descriptions;
}

@Entity
public class Locale
{
    @Id
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class RegionDescription
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private RegionDescriptionPK key;

    @MapsId(value = "regionId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "region_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    })
    private Region region;

    @MapsId(value = "localeName")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "locale", referencedColumnName = "name")
    })
    private Locale locale;
}

@Embeddable
public class RegionDescriptionPK
{
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long regionId;

    @Column(name = "locale")
    private String localeName;
}
```

As a side note, I've seen that this question is quite old. But it isn't closed somehow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@Entity
public class Region
{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateCreation;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "regionDescriptionPK.region")
    private List<RegionDescription> descriptions;
}


@Entity
public class RegionDescription
{
    @EmbeddedId
    private RegionDescriptionPK regionDescriptionPK;    
}

@Embeddable
public class RegionDescriptionPK
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Region_ID")
    private Region region;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "locale")
    private Locale locale;
}

@Entity
public class Locale
{
    @Id
    private String name;
}
```